# One database editable by multiple machines

Tags: java, mysql, server

I am new to coding at this level, and was wondering how I would get a database that multiple users on different networks could edit.

I am trying to make an application where customers of a lawn service can download my "app" or code, insert their address, and update their work log. This information can then be retrieved by the boss on a different machine.

I have a java application that uses swing as the front end. It prompts the user to enter their address, asks them whether they would like to update/retrieve work log/access different dress.

First, I had this data serialized so it could be retrieved later, but this only functions on one machine.

Next, I connected it with MySQL via JDBC so it is stored in a simple table with address as the primary key and work log as the only other column.

At the very least, I would like to figure out how to make this program work so I could export it, send it to someone else, and they could update the same database as me.

I can work on more action listeners etc later, right now I cannot figure out how different machines on different networks can access the same database via an executable jar.

Thanks so much.

*When sending executable jar to another machine, it only has access to *information they enter.

*I want it to have access to previously entered information, as well as *information that may be or may have been entered on other machines.

Comment: End user machines should never access a shared database directly. That's a security nightmare; your users will have access to bypass any data integrity checks or security, including modifying or deleting data for *other users*. You need a web application running on a server to act as a middle man between the database and the user's machine. The web application will be responsible for authenticating the user and enforcing any security constraints, and it will perform all of the database interactions. You can have either a desktop app sending HTTP to the server or just use an actual web site.

Comment: As an aside, before building your own, investigate if a web application that does what you need already exists or not.

Comment: Right, this is more of a learning project for me that may or may not actually be used by the guy I am building it for. Either way it will be small scale and I doubt anyone would try and hack into it, there's no real gain in that. I'm sure there are similar web applications out there that would do the same job, but like I said, I am doing this to learn and gain experience, its not like the guy is paying me haha. Thanks!

Comment: "Either way it will be small scale and I doubt anyone would try and hack into it, there's no real gain in that." Data integrity is as much a concern as security. A mistake can do just as much damage. Regardless, if you're trying to learn, the most valuable lesson you can get is to use the right tool for the job. I have seen many, many problems and much wasted time that could have been avoided by doing so.

Comment: Noted, to boost security then could I just have each user create a username and password? As far as the middle man wouldn't the swing application act as such. As it is set up currently, a window pops up asking them to enter a number depending on what they want to do, and if they decide to add an item to the worklog then that is done on the back end.

Comment: Most databases don't natively support row level controls based on current log in. Even if they do or you hack it with triggers, setting them up would be nearly as much work as implementing it in the app would.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From your explanation, it seems like what you're trying to do is a straightforward client-server application.

- The client : your Java app
- The server : MySQL database server (on a
  web-server online).

So all you need to do is let the client install/access the Java app, and use **one** database.

If it is not compulsory for you to use Java, simply consider a PHP solution, which your users may access using their web browsers.

Comment: The author is writing a desktop application (using the Swing GUI toolkit) to be downloaded to each machine, not a web application. Your mention of using PHP suggests you misunderstood this. Doing what you suggest with a desktop app would require distributing credentials to the database to every machine. Very insecure.

Comment: This seems like a simple way to do it, but I was trying to keep it offline and thus free. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here is an approach that would work for you and allow you to use your swing app with the least amount of object mapping. I assume that’s your goal since you went down the serialization path. Try this:
1. Data in the database is properly normalized to third normal form.
2. The JDBC query executes a stored procedure to get your object data fully denormalized in consumable format.
3. The stored procedure uses SQL command For JSON. 
4. Map the result set to your java object using GSON. GSON will automatically map json to your object.
5. Should the end user change an object, push it back to the database and read it again. Don’t just update it locally.

I store my objects in a hashmap with a unique identifier. That way when I read in an object because it has been updated, inserting into the hashmap with the same unique id with replace the old version with the new. Put a change listener on the hashmap so that you can update the ui when an update is read in from the database. Using javafx you could further map to Observable Lists so the GUI updates automatically.

You could technically do this with the serialized object too. Just store a version ID and a unique ID with the serialized object.

Either way, you would finally create an async task that is periodically checking the version ID in the database against the objects in your hashmap. If the version changes for a particular unique identifier, then bring it in and do your mapping/class loading etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I am going to give this a shot and I'll let you know how it goes. I have a lot to learn, but I love that you gave me a good path to follow and learn along the way. Thanks!